# let в LINQ: почему Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта?

Tags: c#, linq

Метод, с использованием AgilityHtmlPak, должен выкачивать со страницы ссылки, выбрасывая в процессе все лишнее (ссылки на картинки, анкоры и т.д.). По отдельности все работает нормально, а вместе - выбрасывает ошибку:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Crawler.exe
>   Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Вот этот метод:

```
        public List<string> ParserHtml(string uri, string baseUrl)
    {
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(uri);

        var linksOnPage = (from lnks in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                           where lnks.Name == "a" && lnks.Attributes["href"] != null
                           let lnk1 = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value
                           let lnk2 = !lnk1.Contains("rss") ? lnk1 : null
                           let lnk3 = !lnk2.StartsWith("mailto:") ? lnk2 : null
                           select lnk3
              ).Distinct().ToList();

        return linksOnPage;
    }
```

Сами по себе эти куски кода работающие, если например сделать так:

```
                               let lnk2 = !lnk1.Contains("rss") ? lnk1 : null
                           //let lnk3 = !lnk2.StartsWith("mailto:") ? lnk2 : null
                           select lnk2
```

или так:

```
                               //let lnk2 = !lnk1.Contains("rss") ? lnk1 : null
                           let lnk3 = !lnk1.StartsWith("mailto:") ? lnk1 : null
                           select lnk3
```

то по-отдельности нормально работает? т.е. ошибка возникает при вычислении lnk3 из lnk2, то же и наоборот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, Вам встретилась строка, начинающаяся с `rss`.
При вычислении `lnk2` Вы получили `null` - т.е. объекта у Вас нет, а Вы пытаетесь при вычислении `lnk3` вызвать его метод.
Если `lnk2` использовать не будете - замените `let lnk2 = !lnk1.Contains("rss") ? lnk1 : null` на `let lnk2 = !lnk1.Contains("rss") ? lnk1 : ""`. Это не нарушит логику запроса.
Либо обработайте `null` при вычислении `lnk3`: `lnk3 = lnk2==null?null:!lnk2.StartsWith("mailto:") ? lnk2 : null`